# How to disable controls in Windows Media Player in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, media, windows-media-player, mediaelement

I was just wondering if there is a way to disable controls such as ctr Left/Right arrows or Alt+left/right arrows in AxWindowsMediaPlayer. I am using it in WindowsFormsHost in my WPF project. I would like to capture these controls and handle them myself. When I use this block, I don't have any way to prevent it by using e.handeld =true or other ways

```
  void MediaPlayer_KeyDownEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_KeyDownEvent e)
        {

        }
```

Any suggestion how to disable it and continue with my own controls. The important part is it bubbles up somewhere and freezes the GUI if I use such commands, and I don't have any way to capture it to control. It doesn't have any error though.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be blocked in WindowsFormHost level by controlling keydown.

Answer (score 0):

I have one thought to try, but I haven't tested it. Inherit from WindowsFormsHost and override  [WndProc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.wndproc.aspx) method. In this method capture [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912654.aspx) message, process it, and if it's a key you want to suppress, return 0.

If it doesn't work, you may want to find other way to hook windows procedure.

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Anvaka

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on how I can do this?